# How to change crashpad deploy from space bar to another key?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

How can the crashpad deploy be changed from space?

I find myself deploying by accident in the heat of battle, launching me to my death in the storm or some other way.

Specifically, I would like to change deploy of the crashpad from space to another key.

Answer (score 0):

The deploy for your crash pad will always be set to your "jump" key. If you change your jump key or add another secondary bind for jump, you can press a different button to deploy. If what you want is removing space for crashpad, you can not do that.